# systemd-sysctl.service no such file

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, dpkg, systemd, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch 6.6.1 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server. While the installation seemed successful, the elasticsearch service started and successfully returning when I go to localhost:9200, a line during installation read:

```
Setting up elasticsearch (6.6.1) ...
Failed to issue method call: Unit systemd-sysctl.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service' for details.
Created elasticsearch keystore in /etc/elasticsearch
```

The middle line of failed to load systemd-sysctl.service concerned me. I am still new to linux in general and using a relatively old server. This is something to be concerned about and how to approach fixing the problem?

I used `sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-6.6.1.deb` for installation.

Comment: Is [this issue](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/update-problem-procps-failed-to-start-apply-kernel-variables-4175536441/) relevant to your system?

Comment: Unless you've upgraded it somehow, AFAIK 14.04 uses `upstart` rather than `systemd` - perhaps the .deb installer is failing to detect this correctly?